# format column (value) of datatable dynamically

Tags: c#

Is it possible to format a datatable column value at runtime?

I'm trying to show the date inside my `DateTime` column as below,

```
foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    if (c.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        string.Format("MM/dd/yyyy", c);
    }
}
```

but getting full date with time..

**EDIT :**

till now, i'm upto this,..

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
     {
     foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
         if (dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
             if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr[dc])))
              {
               //string s = dr[dc].ToString();
               //dr[dc] = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(' '));
               //dr[dc] = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[dc]).ToShortDateString();
               dr[dc] = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[dc]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
              }
             }
         }
       }
```

still not able to get the desired result

Comment: Have you tried formatting on the UI side? I am sure when you are formatting here, it will give you incorrect time on the UI.

Comment: DateTime does not have a format; a DateTime is just a number. Concepts like "format" apply at the UI when displaying the DateTime.

Comment: i dont want to show `Time` on UI

Comment: @user3085995: where do you show the data in your UI? There you need to apply the format-string or use `dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: i'm exporting my record to Excel

Comment: Of note as to why the above doesn't do anything is that `string.Format` returns a string but you aren't doing anything with the return value. Also you aren't using string.Format properly there either. As others have said though you are best off converting wherever you are exporting if possible so showing the export code is probably best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the solution as below,..

```
                    DataTable dtCloned = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
                    foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
                    {
                        if (c.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            dtCloned.Columns[c.ColumnName].DataType = typeof(string);
                            colNames.Add(c.ColumnName);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
                    }

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtCloned.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dtCloned.Columns)
                        {
                            if (colNames.Contains(dc.ColumnName))
                            {
                                string dt = Convert.ToString(dr[dc]);
                                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dt))
                                {
                                    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Substring(0, dt.IndexOf(' ')), "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                    dr[dc] = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What is colNames in this context